# Consecutive values in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas `df['realize']`

```
time                      realize
2016-01-18 08:25:00     -46.369083
2016-01-19 14:30:00     -819.010738
2016-01-20 11:10:00    -424.955847
2016-01-21 07:15:00     27.523859
2016-01-21 16:10:00     898.522762
2016-01-25 00:00:00    761.063545
```

Where `time` is:

```
df.index = df['time']
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Where `df['realize']` is:

```
In: type(df['realize'])
Out: pandas.core.series.Series
```

I want to count consecutive values, rule is simple (`df['realize'] > 0, df['realize'] < 0`)

Expected out:

```
time                      realize    Consecutive
2016-01-18 08:25:00     -46.369083    1
2016-01-19 14:30:00     -819.010738   2
2016-01-20 11:10:00    -424.955847    3
2016-01-21 07:15:00     27.523859     1
2016-01-21 16:10:00     898.522762    2
2016-01-25 00:00:00    761.063545     3
```

I read about topics about loop, but didn't find what I need. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: hey if there is a 7th row with negative value what should be it consecutive value? 4 or 1?

Comment: @BhanuTez it must be 1

Comment: @Artem Reznov : in order to encourage the users. please consider upvoting and also mark as the answer for the solution you like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
g = df.realize.gt(0).astype(int).diff().fillna(0).abs().cumsum()
df['Consecutive'] = df.groupby(g).realize.cumcount().add(1)

               time     realize       Consecutive
0 2016-01-18 08:25:00  -46.369083            1
1 2016-01-19 14:30:00 -819.010738            2
2 2016-01-20 11:10:00 -424.955847            3
3 2016-01-21 07:15:00   27.523859            1
4 2016-01-21 16:10:00  898.522762            2
5 2016-01-25 00:00:00  761.063545            3
```

---

Where the used grouper is obtained by taking the first differences ([`DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)) of a boolean Series indicating whether or not `realize` is greater than `0`:

```
diff = df.realize.gt(0).astype(int).diff().fillna(0).abs()
df.assign(diff = diff, grouper = g)

         time            realize     Consecutive diff  grouper
0 2016-01-18 08:25:00  -46.369083            1   0.0      0.0
1 2016-01-19 14:30:00 -819.010738            2   0.0      0.0
2 2016-01-20 11:10:00 -424.955847            3   0.0      0.0
3 2016-01-21 07:15:00   27.523859            1   1.0      1.0
4 2016-01-21 16:10:00  898.522762            2   0.0      1.0
5 2016-01-25 00:00:00  761.063545            3   0.0      1.0
```

Comment: With first solution I recieving out `df[['realiz_cash','Consecutive']]`:

`time                      realize    Consecutive
2016-01-18 08:25:00     -46.369083    282
2016-01-19 14:30:00     -819.010738   1
2016-01-20 11:10:00    -424.955847    890
2016-01-21 07:15:00     27.523859     1131
2016-01-21 16:10:00     898.522762    2
2016-01-25 00:00:00    761.063545     1583`

Comment: I was working with a Dataframe, seems like yours could be a pd.Series ? Try doing at the beginning `df = df.reset_index()`

Comment: tried, still got this, let me be more clear -  counting must resets if see changing in it, for example we got streak of 3 positive values, there count = 3, 4-th is negative value, there count must be reset to 1.

Comment: Yes I understood what you're trying to do. I checked again and its working. I'll share the input df aso, but it might have to do with your pandas version or some difference in your df. Make sure that your input df has the same structure, so  time and realize are columns

Comment: I really can't understand why this has 2 downvotes... If I have misunderstood in some way the question please let me know so that I can improve it or correct accordingly. But to downvote in this IMO correct solution makes no sense to me

Comment: This is correctly answers the question and will be significantly more performant than the other posted response.

Comment: @yatu dont know who downvotes, but really appreciate. Checked new solution, it is correct, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My solution.

```
i=0;j=0
def cons(x):
    global i;global j
    if x>0:
        i += 1;j=0
        return i
    else:
        j += 1;i=0
        return j


df['consecutive'] = df['realize'].map(lambda x: cons(x))
```

I hope the solution is helpful.

Comment: This solution is simple and elegant.

Comment: Using globals and ; in python can't be considered "elegant"